# Synology CloudStation Drive client for Ubuntu fails to start

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, nas, synology, qt

I have a Synology NAS, and wanted to try out the CloudStation Drive client for Linux. Downloaded the current deb file for 64bit Ubuntu (I'm using Mint Linux, which is based on Ubuntu) and installed it. Everything went fine until here.

When I start the client from the menu, nothing happens. When I start it from the console, I get this:

```
craesh@denkbrett ~ $ synology-cloud-station-drive
craesh@denkbrett ~ $ lib path = '/opt/Synology/CloudStation/lib/plugins'
../libcommon/SynoLocale.cpp:64 qPrintable(qstrLocaleLower)=[en_us
] 
../libcommon/SynoLocale.cpp:80 qPrintable(qstrLocaleLower)=[en_us] 
../libcommon/SynoLocale.cpp:161 qPrintable(qstrLangFileName)=[:/enu.qm] 
../libcommon/SynoLocale.cpp:138 qPrintable(qstrDef)=[enu
] 

craesh@denkbrett ~ $
```

Looks like there is a version issue with some QT lib, but don't know which. Any idea?

Version of the deb packet is 4.2.2-4379. I also installed the backup client (same version), which works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In my case Cloud Station Drive client stopped to work some time after boot after doing a scan. I though that was the normal behaviour until I discovered the virtulabox doesn't work anymore.
Both were due to the number of inotify so I had to do:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing synology-cloud-station and reinstalling the deb package fixed the same issue for me on 64bit Kubuntu 16.04.

```
sudo apt-get remove synology-cloud-station

sudo dpkg -i synology-cloud-station-drive-4393.x86_64.deb
```

After that you need to setup all your sync tasks again of course.